# Sending mouse clicks to a differnet computer using webrtc

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am trying to connect computer "a" to computer "b" using webrtc and print out the "Click" on computer "b" when the mouse is clicked on computer "a"'s canvas.  I already created a working webrtc example where I make a connection between computer "a" and "b" and send messages between them using textboxes(chat).

I know to Attach a click event to the document. When the user clicks anywhere in the document, output "Click" will be displayed.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
message.value= "Click!";
});
```

And these are some of the webrtc functions I have, I didnt post all my webRTC functions because I dont wanna make the question longer, it already is.

```
// a nice wrapper to send data
function send (room, key, data) {
roomRef.child(room).child(key).set(data);
}

// wrapper function to receive data
function recv (room, type, cb) {
roomRef.child(room).child(type).on("value", function (snapshot, key) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    if (data) { cb(data); }
});
}
// get references to the document tags
var chatlog = document.getElementById("chatlog");
var message = document.getElementById("message");


function bindEvents () {
channel.onopen = function () { console.log("Channel Open"); }
channel.onmessage = function (e) {
    // add the message to the chat log
    chatlog.innerHTML += "<div>Peer says: " + e.data + "</div>";
};
}

// send a message the textbox throught
// the data channel for a chat program
function sendMessage () {
var msg = message.value;
channel.send(msg);
message.value = "";
}
```

My question is I dont know how to connect these two codes together or even if i did, I am not sure if it would work. So my question is how can I click on the canvas on computer "a" and get the textbox to print out "Click" on computer "b".

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into node.js and socket.io.
With these two you could connect multiple clients together and have a real-time communication between them. Other alternative is to use ajax with php, and make one browser to poll for new commands from server, and other browser to send them to server.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Lauri. It seems like since I have already established a connection between two computers using webrtc and send messages between them, I was thinking it wouldnt be too hard to capture a click and write "click" on the other computer. Also I am not familiar with ajax nor php.

Comment: What you could try, is to get a click event on browser ( on canvas for example) and send these coordinates via webrtc to other browser. In the receiving side you would have to simulate / or do the action that the click is supposed to trigger. Maybe if you explained your goal, i could give you a better advice for a technical solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly there. What you can do is, after setting the `message.value` property, is call the `sendMessage()` function. This should trigger the application to send the correct value through the WebRTC Connection.